# How to perform a negative search using regex in angularjs

Tags: regex

What I want to achieve is try and perform a negative search on a regex in angularjs e,g. I want to perform a negative search on a hostname that is not 192.1.1. How do I do this using a custom filter. Can you provide an example of to use the custom filter in this case –

Answer (score 0):

use named group. For example:

```
/[^${192.168.1.1}]/
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific and provide a working example?